# How to take integral of a function with several arguments in Julia?

Tags: julia, integral

Assume I want to calculate the following Integral:
[image]

And the $\lambda_x(w)$ function is:
[image]
where $f_x(w)$ is:
[image]
Consider the following values of variables:
i = 1
σ² = 1
p = q = 1
And the following vector contains the values of ϕₕ and θₕ:

```
coefs = [0.5131, 0.21561]
```

Hence, ϕₕ and θₕ are 0.5131 and 0.21561 respectively. Let's define a function that returns the `log(fₓ(w))` (where `w` is a frequency value, and denoted as `freq` in the following snippet):

```
function λₓw(
  coefs::AbstractVector,
  σ²::AbstractFloat,
  ::Int,
  freq::AbstractFloat,
  p::Int,
  q::Int
)
  0 < freq < π || error("Frequency must be between 0 and π")
  a = σ²/2π
  numerator_ = 0.
  denominator_ = 0.
  for h ∈ 1:p
    x =  * h * freq
    numerator_ += coefs[h] * cis(x)
  end
  for h ∈ 1:q
    x =  * h * freq
    denominator_ += coefs[p + h] * cis(x)
  end
  numerator_ = 1 - numerator_
  denominator_ = 1 - denominator_
  λxw = a*abs(numerator_/denominator_) |> log
  return λxw
end
```

Now, How can I take the Integral of this function from 0 to 1 in order to calculate ψ₀? I know there are some packages for taking integrals, like [`QuadGK`](https://juliamath.github.io/QuadGK.jl/stable/quadgk-examples/) and [`Integrals.jl`](https://docs.sciml.ai/Integrals/stable/) but I did not find similar examples in the corresponding documentation.

**Update:**
I think I'm wrong about the `i` value. I mean, I think `i` is `im` and we can omit it as an argument. I mean the following by `im`:

```
# 3 is an arbitrary value just to show im
julia> 3im
0 + 3im
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is the following one-liner (Thanks to [this blog post](https://techytok.com/lesson-numerical-integration/#functions-with-multiple-arguments)):

```
julia> using QuadGK

julia> quadgk(w->λₓw(coefs, 1., w, 1, 1), 0, 1)
(-2.1349835716325907, 3.865094910793232e-10)
```

However, I do not know why am I getting two values .
Update: I got it. According to the doc:

```
help?> quadgk
search: quadgk quadgk! QuadGK quadgk_print quadgk_count

  quadgk(f, a,b,c...; rtol=sqrt(eps), atol=0, maxevals=10^7, order=7, norm=norm, segbuf=nothing)


  Numerically integrate the function f(x) from a to b, and optionally over additional intervals b to c and so on. Keyword options include a relative error tolerance rtol (if
  atol==0, defaults to sqrt(eps) in the precision of the endpoints), an absolute error tolerance atol (defaults to 0), a maximum number of function evaluations maxevals (defaults    
  to 10^7), and the order of the integration rule (defaults to 7).

  Returns a pair (I,E) of the estimated integral I and an estimated upper bound on the absolute error E. If maxevals is not exceeded then E <= max(atol, rtol*norm(I)) will hold.     
  (Note that it is useful to specify a positive atol in cases where norm(I) may be zero.)
```

Also, it would be great to know an answer using `Integrals.jl`.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted in your answer, you can just define the parameters (the inputs you aren't integrating over) in the anonymous function you pass to quadgk, so that it will recognize which single variable you actually intend to integrate over.

As for Integrals.jl, it expects you to define an [IntegralProblem](https://docs.sciml.ai/Integrals/stable/basics/IntegralProblem/) which you then pass to [solve](https://docs.sciml.ai/Integrals/stable/basics/solve/) to evaluate it.

An `IntegralProblem` only accepts functions in the form `f(x,p)` (functions returns the result as new object) or `f(y,x,p)` (function returns the result in `y`). So you would need to put your function in one of these forms, defining the parameters within the function itself, e.g.

```
function λₓw(freq, params)
  coeffs = params[1]
  p = params[2]
  ...
```

The actual calls to integrate/solve would then look something like this (not by a computer with Julia at the moment, so couldn't test the syntax).

```
prob=IntegralProblem(f=λₓw,lb=0,ub=1,p=[coefs, 1., 1, 1])
solve(prob)

# Use different params
remake(prob, p=new_params)
solve(prob)
```

Comment: Can you please bring more code? I have ambiguities in defining `IntegralProblem` and fusing it into `solve`. BTW I got your point on the `λₓw`.